# This localhost page can’t be found. No webpage was found for the web address "..."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to create a web API, but when I execute the program the following message pops up:
This localhost page can’t be found. No webpage was found for the web address "TheAdress".

I am learning, so I am not sure if the code I am gonna post will help (it is all the code that I have written).

Controllers:

```
namespace ApiPractice.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")] //puts the endpoint communication in "Auto" (It takes it from AutoController)
    [ApiController] //automate code 
    public class AutoController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly AplicationDbContext context;
        public AutoController(AplicationDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Usuarios>> Get()
        {
            return context.Users.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Entities:

```
namespace ApiPractice.Entities
{
    public class Usuarios
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Contexts

```
namespace ApiPractice.Context
{
    public class AplicationDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public AplicationDbContext (DbContextOptions<AplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) //does some weird shit, but it works.
        { }

        public DbSet<Usuarios> Users { get; set; }  //Somehow the database creates a table based on Users.
    }
}
```

Startup.cs, ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //No idea what this does, but I needed for the creation of the table
    services.AddDbContext<AplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))); 

    services.AddControllers();
}
```

I also changed the launch browser property on the debug menu inside the properties of the project for api/autores... No idea why I had to do it...

That is all, if you need anything else I will provide it to you as soon as I see your request, thank you so much for your time, hope everyone has a good day. (:

Comment: What address are you browsing to?

Comment: https://localhost:xxxxx/api/autores                xxxxx = a five digit number, I dont post it because I am not sure if I can do it

Comment: Why "autores" in your URL? It should be "auto" because your controller is "AutoController".

Comment: @mason Ok, I just copied what a guy did on a video and didn't realize I didn't use the same name for the class hahaha, it works now, thank you so much, You can answer the question if you want the reputation btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong URL as @mason pointed out.